# Strongswan creating client to server connection VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, strongswan

I'm having problems with my client-to-server config.
I only edited this file /etc/ipsec.conf
I can only edit this file on Client side, but not server side. On server I have an interface program where I can create certs and other stuff.

```
config setup
        charondebug="all"
        uniqueids=yes
conn devgateway-to-prodgateway
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=rsasig
        left=externalIP-A
        leftsubnet=InternalIP-A/24
        leftcert=myServerPem.pem
        right=ExternalIP-B
        rightsubnet=InternalIP-B/24
        rightcert=myServerPem.pem (downloaded this cert, created by my server)
        ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
        esp=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
        aggressive=no
        keyingtries=%forever
        ikelifetime=36000s
        lifetime=10800s
        dpddelay=30s
        dpdtimeout=120s
        dpdaction=restart
```

I can ping from my A client to B server IP, but when using `ipsec status` I receive the next message:

```
Security Associations (0 up, 1 connecting):
devgateway-to-prodgateway[1]: CONNECTING, ExternalIp-A[%any]...ExternalIp-B[%any]
```

So it's not properly working as desired.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the log for details. Ideally, also check the log on the responder.

Comment: I checked it already but I'm only receiving this messages...

- Apr 26 09:53:03 compu-vpn ipsec[594]: 04[NET] error writing to socket: Network is unreachable.
- Apr 26 09:53:03 compu-vpn ipsec[594]: 06[IKE] giving up after 5 retransmits.
- Apr 26 09:53:03 compu-vpn ipsec[594]: 06[IKE] peer not responding, trying again (36/0)
```

Comment: I'd recommend you remove `left=externalIP-A`, in particular if `externalIP-A` is not actually an address on this host. But also check that `ExternalIP-B` is the correct IP.

Comment: I think it could be a firewall problem or a problem with certs. At this point I've changed and added some things to ipsec.conf. Any other suggestion? ExternalIP-B seems to be good

Comment: Firewall is a possibility, make sure UDP ports 500 and 4500 are reachable. IP fragmentation due to large certificates is another possible issue, make sure IKEv2 fragmentation is supported and enabled by the peer. Without knowing what message was retransmitted above, it's difficult to say more (i.e. add the complete log to your question).